# How to add animations in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, wxpython

I made a basic but functional to do list app in wxPython and want to take it to the next level. By next level I mean after you delete or add a task, it should slowly been seen moving up like Google Keep.  I was just wondering how I could do this to make a more professional application. Thanks a bunch in advance!